# Why does my Mosquitto broker fail to start on boot, but works when started manually?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, mosquitto

I have a UDOO x86 running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, with Mosquitto v2.  This setup has worked as expected until a recent Ubuntu update.

Now, Mosquitto fails to start on boot.  In the Mosquitto log file I see that it correctly finds my config file, but then fails with:

```
Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
Error: Cannot assign requested address
```

It then immediately attempts to restart four more times in rapid succession before (apparently) giving up.

Strangely, if I start Mosquitto manually (using `sudo systemctl start mosquitto`) immediately after boot, the broker starts without error and works properly (both listeners, see below).

My mosquitto.conf:

```
log_type all
allow_anonymous true
listener 1883 10.11.12.222  # <-- local IP address of my machine
listener 1883 localhost
```

I've determined that the error is caused by the line with the IP address.  If I use only localhost, or if I just use `listener 1883` (which I think binds to all adapters?), mosquitto starts and works correctly.

The computer has two network adapters -- an Ethernet adapter statically assigned to 10.11.12.222, and a wireless adapter on a different subnet (using DHCP) connected to the interwebs.  I'd like limit my listener to the Ethernet adapter only (and localhost), hence the desire to specify the IP address.

I've tried turning off `allow_anonymous` and adding a password file -- this doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: Does the ethernet adaptor get it's address via DHCP or is it static?

Comment: The Ethernet adapter is static...updated question to clarify.

Comment: Then the only way it should be able to fail like that is if you are trying to start Mosquitto before the network  has been brought up.

Comment: @hardillb: This makes sense -- any idea how that could have happened, or how to diagnose?

Comment: You'd have to look at the systemd files

Comment: @hardillb: Guided by your advice and [this post](https://opensource.com/article/20/5/systemd-troubleshooting-tool), I was able to find `/lib/systemd/system/mosquitto.service` on my system and change `network.target` to `network-online.target`. This resolved the problem! Thank you!